# How to use FileWriter Filter in DirectShow

Tags: c++, directshow

I have trouble using the filewriter filter. I am not sure on how to set the outputfile.
It has a interface IFileSinkFilte with a method SetFileName.
The problem i have is that i don't know how to set the AM_MEDIA_TYPE structure it uses.
It looks as following:

```
typedef struct _MediaType {
  GUID     majortype;
  GUID     subtype;
  BOOL     bFixedSizeSamples;
  BOOL     bTemporalCompression;
  ULONG    lSampleSize;
  GUID     formattype;
  IUnknown *pUnk;
  ULONG    cbFormat;
  BYTE     *pbFormat;
} AM_MEDIA_TYPE;
```

How do I know the sample size?

What is a format bloock?

How do i get its length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set the MediaType, just set it `NULL`.

Or you can set a partial MediaType. So '0' everything and then set only `majortype` and `subtype`. (e.g. `MEDIATYPE_Stream` and `MEDIASUBTYPE_NULL`)

Comment: `nullptr` is better than `NULL`.

Comment: when i set it to NULL i get an access read memory at position 0x00000000.

Comment: That's strange, are you really calling `IFileSinkFilter::SetFileName(pathToVideo, NULL);` ? Can you show some sample code, maybe it's not the mediatype but the string of the filename?

Answer (score -1):

1. Use GraphEdit from Windows SDK, or similar tool like GraphStudioNext
2. Build file capturing topologies interactively to get idea of File Writer use scenarios, see [Capturing Video to an AVI File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for explanations
3. Review media types in graphs from item 2 above and then build similar graphs programmatically